# Should I use Hibernate cache when I have clustered server which writes 15000 records per 30sec to database?

Tags: hibernate, caching, ehcache

Should I use Hibernate cache when I have clustered server which updates/writes 15000 records per 30sec to database? Or I am only able to query and update directly to database?

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate caching is best suited for select operations (using cache reduces the number of calls made to the db), however for save or update operations cache would not be greatly helpful (again, there is some help offered)...

I'd recommend you to not cache the tables / pojos which are involved in such heavy save or update operation and try to use [spring batching](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/) this would improve the performance.